# Slick slider - first slide doesn't show on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

Trying to get slick sliders to work inside a container that animates into view... Clicking on a box title drops down a full width content box with a slick slider and some paragraphs about the project.

My problem is that the first image doesn't automatically show up for me on load... I have to click "next" a couple of times to get it to show up.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the way I'm defining height/widths on my slick slides... but I can't figure it out.

Any help?

https://codepen.io/Finches/pen/vpZqYR

```
/** Slick slider **/
.slide img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
.slick-track {
  float:left;
}

.slick-prev {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.slick-next {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -30px;
  right: 25px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to have something to do with incorporating Slick's setPosition... But I can't get it to work.

Comment: Fixed this by calling my Slick sliders to be created and destroyed within the jQuery parent container toggle.